# Apidaze REST API HTTP POST Call in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, python, rest, sms

I am trying to send SMS messages when a button is clicked in an Android app. I have the SMS sending code in Python using a REST API. The template looks like so:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.apidaze.io/{{api_key}}/sms/send"

querystring = {"api_secret":"{{api_secret}}"}

payload = "from=15558675309&to=15551234567&body=Have%20a%20great%20day."

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, 
params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Because I am making an Android app, I need this to be in Java, but I am having trouble making the same POST request with the same parameters, headers, and body in JAVA.

Does anyone know how to make convert this template into something I can use for an Android app in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a port of Apache Http Client for Android:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Check the documentation, a simple POST request is very easy using this library:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.apidaze.io/" + api_key + "/sms/send");

String json = "{"api_secret":" + api_secret + "}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```